# How to escape special characters in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter

I'm building a website in Code Igniter and i'm trying to save products in a database. I don't know what kind of products i get. It's a XML file. There ara some times special characters in it so Code Igniter crashes.
I fixed it like this

```
$search = array('â', 'à', 'á', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'Â', '€', 'š', '¢', 'Ã');
str_replace($search, '', $string)
```

But this is not nice and i haven't coverd all the possible special characters.
My question is: is there a eassier way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short answer but I think you have issues regarding handling UTF8 encoded characters and need to read this (a guide to working with PHP, MySQL and UTF8 character encoding - other guides are available )  -

http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should take look at convert_accented_characters() function of Text Helper in CI

> It transliterates high ASCII characters to low ASCII equivalents,
>   useful when non-English characters need to be used where only standard
>   ASCII characters are safely used, for instance, in URLs.
>
> $string = convert_accented_characters($string); This function uses a
>   companion config file application/config/foreign_chars.php to define
>   the to and from array for transliteration.